What really happens inside ADC chip?
I know analog signal is input and output of ADC is 0100100001...
Wikipedia and other sites shows me a graph of  Digital out vs. analog in.
I am mature enough to believe that ADC won't plot a graph
of Digital out vs. analog in.
I want to know what happens inside the spike legged Chip.

How did time enter this question? Usually, a voltage characteristic curve is plotted. Digital out vs. analog in.

@a360pilot I corrected my question, thank you.

Do manufacturer articles such as the TI How delta-sigma ADCs work, Part 1 How delta-sigma ADCs work, Part 2 or the Analog Sigma-Delta ADC Tutorial help? I'm not sure what level of detail is needed.

What is a spike legged Chip?  Do you mean a DIP (Dual Inline Package).  There are many types of ADC and each operates differently.  Do some research and ask about a specific type.


Wikipedia and other sites shows me a graph of Digital out vs. analog in

The graph is a visual representation of a static transfer function. The graph is for humans. The static transfer function is a formal and abstract description of the A/D converter's function. It tells us what the converter does, but not how it does it.
Abstract, in this case, means that the function is an idea, it's not tangible - not something you can touch or make, it's not a physical object.

I am mature enough to believe that ADC won't plot a graph of Digital out vs. analog in.

The plot should not really have entered your mind, because a plot is a descriptive entity. It doesn't do any work, it only describes in what way something (being plotted) behaves.

I want to know what happens inside the spike legged Chip.

You just need to keep reading that Wikipedia article. It does a fair job.
Here's the section you're looking for: Analog-to-digital converter: Types.


....but not how it does it.

So where can I learn ADC works without wikipedia?

@M.JonesClone by taking a college-level course on data converters, reading proceedings of ISSCC on data converters, and so on.

@M.JonesClone Look for quality books about data conversion. Some are available for free download. Start with The Data Conversion Handbook - https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-books/data-conversion-handbook.html
